# Uncaught TypeError: TypeScript class constructor is not a function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm, webpack-dev-server

I have a class in one file and I'm trying to create new objects from it that are loaded up in my E2E $httpBackend, but the browser can't seem to figure it out. The whole application doesn't load and this error appears in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: app.Challenge is not a function

The TyepScript compiler (I'm using WebStorm to auto-compile.) has no complaints and it compiles fine. The module with the class is like so:

```
module app {
  "use strict";

    // interfaces here

    export class Challenge implements IChallenge {

        constructor(public answerString: string,
                    public difficulty: number,
                    public id: string,
                    public language: languages,
                    public name: string,
                    public tests: ITest[]) {
        }
    }
}
```

And my mockBackend for my angular app is this:

```
module app.development {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("appMock", ["ngMockE2E"])
        .run(challengeResourceMock);

    challengeResourceMock.$inject = ["$httpBackend"];
    function challengeResourceMock($httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService): void {
        var challenges: app.IChallenge[] = [];
        var challenge: app.IChallenge;


        challenge = new app.Challenge( // <-- It says this is not a function!
            "runThisFunction = function(str) {\n\treturn str.split('').reverse().join('');\n}",
            1, "1", 1, "Reverse a String", [{
                description: "make sure it reverses the string (e.g. 'start' will become 'trats)",
                test: "function () {\n\tvar a = 'abcdef';\n\texpect(runThisFunction(a)).toEqual('fedcba');\n}"
            }]);
        challenges.push(challenge);

        // ...more challenges added to the list

        // get all challenges
        $httpBackend.whenGET("api/challenge").respond(200, challenges);

        // pass through requests for anything else
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/./).passThrough();
    }

}
```

How do I clear the error and get my app working with the mock backend?

## UPDATE:

I've now removed the TypeScript modules. On basarat's advice I'm only using commonjs modules. I'm now using the ts-loader with webpack instead of WebStorm's compiler. I added a tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "outDir": "./dist/tsOutput/",
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true
    },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "trash", "coverage"]
}
```

Currently everything is in the global space, which isn't ideal but the application isn't big enough yet for there to be any conflicts. I'm, now, getting a slightly different error message, but the effect is the same. The application won't run.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Challenge is not defined

"Build" doesn't seem to be working. My IDE's inspector has no complaints. It's as if "class" isn't doing anything at all.

## TEMPORARY HACK

Well, after fiddling for quite a while, I decided I was running out of time and decided to replace my Challenge objects with object literals.

```
module app {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("appMock", ["ngMockE2E"])
        .run(challengeResourceMock);

    challengeResourceMock.$inject = ["$httpBackend"];
    function challengeResourceMock($httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService): void {
        var challenges: app.IChallenge[] = [];
        var challenge: app.IChallenge;

        challenge = {
            answerString: "runThisFunction = function(str) {\n\treturn str.split('').reverse().join('');\n}",
            difficulty: 1,
            id: "1",
            language: 1,
            name: "Reverse a String",
            tests: [{
                description: "make sure it reverses the string (e.g. 'start' will become 'trats)",
                test: "function () {\n\tvar a = 'abcdef';\n\texpect(runThisFunction(a)).toEqual('fedcba');\n}"
            }]
        };
        challenges.push(challenge);

        // additional obj literal challenges    

        // get all challenges
        $httpBackend.whenGET("api/challenge").respond(200, challenges);

        // pass through requests for anything else
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/./).passThrough();
    }

}
```

Obviously, I must return to this issue in the future, but I'm further in my project for now.

Comment: Since you are now using commonjs (which is a good thing), did you `import {Challenge} from ' ./Challenge.ts'` in your second file ?

Comment: Darn. I wanted that to be the solution. :D The compiler is now giving error "TS2307: Cannot find module './challenge.ts'". I have been using "require's". Everything in my application should be concatenated and in the same name space. I see the challenge.ts file in the list of file bundled by webpack.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: app.Challenge is not a function

A common issue with using `--out`. Please use external modules (prefer `--module commonjs`).

## Docs

https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

## More

Another answer: [typescript output order - gulp equivalent to tsc with tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274909/typescript-output-order-gulp-equivalent-to-tsc-with-tsconfig-json/35281469#35281469)

Comment: So, are you saying forget the "module's"? I thought they were needed for good namespaceing?

Comment: I'm using WebStorm. I've been letting it automatically compile the ts for me. Will I have to switch to some build tool?

Comment: Here is some info straight out of jetbrains blog : https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/